# Azure Service Fabric Java SSL/HTTPS server

Tags: java, ssl, https, server, azure-service-fabric

I have been looking into the Azure Service Fabric development and I have successfully created some test HTTP Stateless-Service applications in Java. Now I'd like to use encrypted api server communication in form of HTTPS but I cannot find any information how such server could be set up in Service Fabric environment.

In my HTTP applications I have been using `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` class and when I checked into the `HttpsServer` class I could not figure out how I could get the certificate saved into the application so that it could be used with the `HttpsServer` class. All the example applications using `HttpsServer` seem to read the certificate file from disk and that is not possible in ServiceFabric environment as far as I know.

So what is the proper way to set up HTTPS server in Java Service Fabric Stateless-Service application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy [certificates](https://github.com/ChackDan/Service-Fabric/blob/master/Scripts/CertUpload4Linux/CreateAndUploadtoKeyvault.md) to cluster nodes using the ARM template.

Alternatively:
You can also use dotnet core and Kestrel for this. Here are some links to get started.

[Github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-core-getting-started)

[Channel9 Video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MVP-Azure/A-quick-demo-of-Azure-Service-Fabric-with-ASPNET-Core)

[Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/13/hosting-net-core-services-on-service-fabric/)

You can also choose to run a web server like [NodeJS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-multiple-apps) or [Flask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-containers-linux) as a [container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-container-linux) on Service Fabric.

Comment: Could you point to some reference about how to use ARM on local development cluster? Also from where and how do I load the SSL certificate from my Java code so that I can pass it to the HttpsServer object after it has been set to the cluster by ARM template?

Comment: Using ARM is only possible on Azure /Azure Stack. On your development cluster (your dev machine) you can use certificates from disk (which works the same as in any other local app), as all nodes run on one machine.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. One more guestion; where do the certificates go in a production environment (in Azure) when I deploy them from KeyVault using ARM template? Most importantly how do I access the certificate from the Java app in runtime when clusters are running in azure? Will the certificate be available on some standard location on the cluster machine where my app can load it from?

Comment: it's deployed in /var/lib/waagent with the thumbprint as file name, provided you have proper rights, you can access it there.